# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: " "

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to display all the products on my JSP page added by that user. When the user logs in, they can add the products. I want to display all the products added by them using their email. That is, all the records which were added by using that email should be displayed to them. So far, I can only display only one record per user

For example, if the user has added 5 products, only the first one will be displayed on the JSP page, but I want all 5 products to be shown.

I think my code is correct, but I guess I have some issue with my query. Can someone please help?

For understanding, I'll add my code and the queries I have tried.

DAO:

```java
public List<Product> select_products_added_by_user(User user) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.initializeDatabase();
    
    List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();  

//  String query = "select * from productlist where added_by_user = ?" ;    // This query will return only one record per user.
    String query = "select * from productlist where added_by_user in(select added_by_user from productlist group by added_by_user having count(*) > 1 ) = ? ";    

// The above query will return this error (ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "email used for logging in") 

    PreparedStatement prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    prestmt.setString(1,user.email); 
        
    ResultSet rs = prestmt.executeQuery();
        
    if(rs.next())
    {   
        int id = rs.getInt("id");                            
        String code = rs.getString("code");
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        int price = rs.getInt("price");
        String home_main_category = rs.getString("home_main_category");
        String home_sub_category = rs.getString("home_sub_category");
        String p_avail = rs.getString("p_avail");
        String p_act = rs.getString("p_act");
        String pro_exp_date = rs.getString("pro_exp_date");
        String pro_manufacture_date = rs.getString("pro_manufacture_date");  
        String added_by_user = rs.getString("added_by_user");
        
        listProduct.add(new Product(id,code,name,price,home_main_category,home_sub_category,p_avail,p_act,pro_exp_date,pro_manufacture_date,added_by_user));
    }
    return listProduct;     
}
```

Stack Trace

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "sk@gmail.com"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2565)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2297)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:322)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
    at com.pamposh.java.ProductDAO.select_products_added_by_user(ProductDAO.java:107)
    at com.pamposh.java.ControllerServlet.select_products_added_by_user(ControllerServlet.java:525)
    at com.pamposh.java.ControllerServlet.doGet(ControllerServlet.java:83)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Replace `if(rs.next())` with `while(rs.next())`. Also, the title of your question seems unrelated to the question asked in the body of your question. If the error in the title is part of your problem, please make that clear in the body of your question, and include the full exception stacktrace, or otherwise rewrite the title to summarize your actual problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for the suggestion but getting same error again any other way ?? 
yeah will edit the question !!

Comment: Ok, looking at your query condition, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this `WHERE` clause: `where added_by_user in(select added_by_user from productlist group by added_by_user having count(*) > 1 ) = ?`. The result of `in(...)` is boolean, so comparing it against an email address makes no sense, and is the cause of that error. However, your commented out query should work just fine after replacing that `if` with a `while`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks!! your suggestion worked i got what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Either you indeed intended

```
        prestmt.setBoolean(1, ... some condition ...);
```

or you wanted to compare the email field.

```
String query = """
    select *
    from productlist
    where added_by_user in
        (select added_by_user
        from productlist
        group by added_by_user
        having count(*) > 1 )
    and email = ? """;    

try (PreparedStatement prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    prestmt.setString(1, user.email); 
    
    try (ResultSet rs = prestmt.executeQuery()) {
        List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {   
            int id = rs.getInt("id");                            
            String code = rs.getString("code");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            int price = rs.getInt("price");
            String home_main_category = rs.getString("home_main_category");
            String home_sub_category = rs.getString("home_sub_category");
            String p_avail = rs.getString("p_avail");
            String p_act = rs.getString("p_act");
            String pro_exp_date = rs.getString("pro_exp_date");
            String pro_manufacture_date = rs.getString("pro_manufacture_date");  
            String added_by_user = rs.getString("added_by_user");
    
            listProduct.add(new Product(id, code, name, price, home_main_category,
                home_sub_category, p_avail, p_act, pro_exp_date, pro_manufacture_date,
                added_by_user));
        }
        return listProduct;     
    }
}
```

The try-with-resources closes statement and result set.

`listProduct` is best declared just before its usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's already solved as the suggestion given above but i really appreciate the time you have taken to give the answer !!